# Can I still travel back to Canada by using the new passport with no document and the old passport with valid visa and study permit?

Tags: visas, paperwork, passport-renewals, permits

Just like I said, I have two passports right now. My old passport with valid visa and study permit is about to expire at september this year. Since then, I applied for a new passport to replace my old one. I am just wondering that if I can still use the visa and study permit on my old passport with my new passport to re-enter Canada before the expired date of my visa?